# How to properly inject the ObjectManager into Fieldsets?

Tags: dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entitymanager, fieldset

I am struggling with a proper injection of Doctrine's ObjectManager to my Fieldsets. I do not want to pass it over all constructors to them. The case is as follows:

Controllers:

- Controllers have no ObjectManager.
- Controllers use Services.

Services:

- Services implement the ObjectManagerAwareInterface.
- Services get the ObjectManager by an Initializer class.
- Services provide Forms.

Forms:

- Forms should not have an ObjectManager - at least they do not need one so far.
- Forms create the respective Fieldsets.

Fieldsets:

- Fieldsets implement the ObjectManagerAwareInterface.

As it is now I pass the ObjectManager **from** the Service **over** the Form **to** the Fieldset. This approach is very ugly.

I know that there is a solution using the FormElementManager. But in order to do that I would have to give the Form access to the ServiceLocator by injecting it. This approach seems not to be more proper than my current one.

**The question is** how to inject Doctrine's ObjectManager into my Fieldsets without injecting the global ServiceLocator (or something else) into my Forms. I would like to leave the Forms simple as they are if possible.

The following shows roughly how my application is built up right now:

```
abstract class AbstractService implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{

    private $objectManager;

    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }

    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

        return $this;
    }

}

class MyService extends AbstractService
{

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $count = $this->someCalculation();
        $myForm = new MyForm($count, $this->getObjectManager());

        // ...
    }

}

class MyForm extends Form
{

    private $objectManager;

    public function __construct($count, ObjectManager $objectManager) // TODO: Remove $objectManager
    {
        parent::__construct('myForm');

        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

        $myCollection = new Collection('myCollection');
        $myCollection->setCount($count);
        $myCollection->setTargetElement(new MyFieldset($objectManager)); // TODO: ???
        $myCollection->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($myCollection);

        $submit = new Submit('submit');
        $this->add($submit);
    }
}

abstract class AbstractFieldset extends Fieldset
                                implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{

    private $objectManager;

    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }

    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

        return $this;
    }

}

class MyFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager) // TODO: Remove $objectManager
    {
        parent::__construct('myFieldset');

        $this->setObjectManager($objectManager); // TODO: Use initializer

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($this->getObjectManager(), true));
        $this->setObject(new MyModel());

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you'd wanna be using the `FormElementManager`.

```
// Config array
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        'My\Cool\Fieldset' => 'My\Cool\FieldsetFactory'
    ]
]
```

And then you have  anormal factory-class

```
class FieldsetFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $realServiceLocator = $sl->getServiceLocator();
        $entityManager      = realServiceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        return new \My\Cool\Fieldset($entityManager);
    }
}
```

That would be the most proper way to do it.

Comment: +1 I would add that the fieldset, if added via `$this->add()` in the form, has access to the `FormElementManager` via the `FormFactory` (so no need to inject the service locator)